# Incompatible architectures when linking to static library on iOS Simulator using Qt

Tags: c++, ios, qt

while building my Qt project, an iOS app, I'm getting a symbols not found error for a missing architecture (i386).

The project uses subdirs which again contain 2 self written libraries and an app which links to them.

After some investigating I found out that my libraries use armv7 and arm64 while my app uses i386. What I'm getting from this is that the linker doesn't seem to find the libraries with their respective architectures.

This is what I get from the compiler while building:

> ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/me/myprojects/build-myproject-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_7_1_for_iOS-Release/install/lib/libwebdav.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/me/myprojects/build-myproject-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_7_1_for_iOS-Release/install/lib/libwebdav.a (2 slices)ignoring file /Users/me/myprojects/build-myproject-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_7_1_for_iOS-Release/install/lib/libcommon.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/me/myprojects/build-myproject-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_7_1_for_iOS-Release/install/lib/libcommon.a (2 slices)
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "CalendarEvent::staticMetaObject", referenced from:
>         qt_meta_extradata_QMLEventWrapper in moc_qmleventwrapper.o
>         int qRegisterMetaType(char const*, CalendarEvent::APM_TYPE*, QtPrivate::MetaTypeDefinedHelper::Defined) && (!(QMetaTypeId2::IsBuiltIn))>::DefinedType) in moc_qmleventwrapper.o
>     "CalendarEvent::colorHex() const", referenced from:
>         QMLEventWrapper::color() const in qmleventwrapper.o
>
> ...
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> ...
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>   The following build commands failed:
>       Ld myproject.build/Release-iphonesimulator/myproject.build/Objects-normal/i386/myproject normal i386
>   (1 failure)
>   make[1]: *** [xcodebuild-release-iphonesimulator] Error 65
>   make: *** [sub-app-make_first] Error 2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run it on an simulator, which supports architectures i386/x86_64 (the processor of your computer).

Workaround:

Test on a device instead of the simulator

Solution:

Build all used libraries for i386/x86_64 also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention that I already tried building it for a device and this works without any issues. Also, how do I accomplish building my libraries for said architectures using qmake and my .pro files?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe [this thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/57402-How-to-determine-target-architecture-in-qmake-project-file) is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was a bug in qmake.
In a very desperate attempt I installed Qt 5.8.0 and tried compiling again. Worked like a charm.
I was using Qt 5.7.1 before which tried to build the libraries for the iPhone instead of the simulator resulting in the wrong architecture. 
See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58007